# Image assets is renamed by Electron-Builder

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, electron

I have an angular application built with electron-builder on mac. Inside there are two ways in which I use images, for different purposes.

HTML:

```html
<img src="./cat_logo.png"/>
```

CSS:

```css
#logo{
    content: url("../../../../assets/img/cat_logo.png");
}
```

However, after building, the `cat_logo.png` is renamed by electron-builder. Because of that, the HTML cannot resolve the image, while the CSS can resolve the image with the renamed file name..

The `cat_logo.png` is renamed to `cat_logo.80c084d6d8f0a23f4b87.png`. the path is exactly the same except the file name.

[screenshot of network from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MGN2.png)

Why does electron-builder rename the image file during bundling? And how does it do it? Can it be disabled?

Comment: This is called fingerprinting (or possibly asset revisioning) and is done to avoid cache releated problems. I would guess that the fingerprinting is configured to handle html and css files but not JS-files (which seems to be what your templates are compiled into). My guess is that this isn't electron-builder doing this (but I could be wrong) but instead Angular when doing a production build.

Comment: I tried to build the angular first before the electron. it seems the image in dist folder already rename the image file before any electron process being executed. I finally did workaround to fix the issue, by copying the file after angular build finished

Comment: As I said then, it is angular that is doing this. Try building the files with `ng build --prod=true --outputHashing=none`. Other build settings can be seen here: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: Anno 2024 still an issue.